# Is there any way to call more than one function from a vue.js directive?

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to call more than one function from a vue.js directive?

I know that I could create a function that calls the other two.

What I would like to know if I can call, from the html file, two functions for the same event.

For instance:

```
<input type="text"
       v-on:keyup.enter="myFirstFunction()"
       v-on:keyup.enter="mySecondFunction()"    
>
</input>
```

Unfortunately, it seems that this only bind the first function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text"
       v-on:keyup.enter="myFirstFunction() & mySecondFunction()"
>
</input>
```

Answer (score 1):

this cannot really work since directives like `v-on:keyup` are simply element attributes to the browser, and you can't have duplicate attributes on an element.

So yes, you will have to create a method that calls the other two.

> The functions are not related between them and they are not used in the same combination through the code, so, it doesn't make sense add code that composes them

I don't see it that way. In this scenario, the functions obvously *are* related - they are called from the same event. a simple two-line method solves the issue.

Comment: The 'not duplicate attributes on an element' explanation makes sense, but I was thinking that maybe vue.js allowed call two functions from the same attribute. I'm going to wait a little and if nobody show me that is possible I will accept your answer.

Comment: About the related functions: they are only related in the sense that they are happening after the same event, but not in a conceptual sense. My understanding is that If there is only a situation where this happen, we are adding code that doesn't abstract anything. Imagine that you have 20 different functions that combine in different ways; you would finish with a function for every possible combination. In this situation, the sane thing is call every function separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your second function in your first function instead, or make a third function that has calls both functions in it, then call it. This is because the event is only recognized once.

Comment: This is precisely what I'm trying to avoid (as I said in the question). The functions are not related between them and they are not used in the same combination through the code, so, it doesn't make sense add code that composes them.